# laravel fluent update two tables

Tags: laravel

I have two tables I want to update with one query, but I cannot find how to do this?

```
    $update = DB::table('users')
        ->join('addresses', 'users.id', '=', 'addresses.user_id')
        ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->update(array(
            'firstname' =>  $userDetails['firstname'],
            'lastname'  =>  $userDetails['lastname'],
            'email'     =>  $userDetails['email'],
            'password'  =>  $userDetails['password'],
            'addresses.add_line1'       =>  $userDetails['addl1'],
            'addresses.add_line2'       =>  $userDetails['addl2'],
            'addresses.town'            =>  $userDetails['town'],
            'addresses.county'      =>  $userDetails['county'],
            'addresses.post_code'       =>  $userDetails['postcode']

        ));

    dd($update);
```

But i get this returned

```
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'add_name_no' in 'field list'
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no easy way around this other than to write a custom query using DB::raw();

Even though you have added the JOIN method, laravel does not include join in the query when updating. I'm not 100% sure of the reason for this, but it has something to do with difference between different database engines.

UPDATE

Although it does look like laravel 4 will have this feature https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/57e11e392447206f60d77b33c0646229842315a3

Have just added it to my laravel application and it works a treat!